# Why is media query applying to a smaller value than what I set?

Tags: html, css, media

I am using js to monitor the mouse xy and when I shrink the window, the media applies to a value that I did not ask. What can be causing this calculus error? Is it the browser-side scrollbar? I am using Brave browser to test this, and it doesn't matter if I try "min-width" or "max-width", the value I set, it only applies less than it, as the images show below.

[image]
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #222, #444, black);
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, purple, yellow, black);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="window-properties"></span>
  <script>
    let windowEl = document.querySelector('.window-properties')
    setInterval(() => {
      let width  = windowEl.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || 
      document.body.clientWidth;
      let height = windowEl.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| 
      document.body.clientHeight;
      windowEl.innerHTML = `${width}, ${height}`
    }, 1)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tested your media query, it works as expected. max-width 1000px means anything less than 1000px will have that linear gradient which is what I see on my end.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either, but on my screen, testing this template on my laptop, it applies until 983px, not 1000px, as I set. This is what I'm trying to understand. No matter what value I set, it applies: (the value - some pixels), in this case, 17. I just set it to1020px, and it stopped applying it at 1003px. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem are the margins and paddings that are taken into account in your calculations.

Take a look at this example. I have added a couple of css lines to remove the paddings and margins, and then it seems to work well.

```js
let windowEl = document.querySelector('.window-properties')
setInterval(() => {
  let width = windowEl.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
    document.body.clientWidth;
  let height = windowEl.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
  windowEl.innerHTML = `${width}, ${height}`
}, 1)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #222, #444, black);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, purple, yellow, black);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="window-properties"></span>
```

Comment: One tiny detail you look at the code and don't realize it. Thank you very much for the support. Now I understand why people use these default properties so often.

Answer (score 1):

The media query is working perfectly OK.

Your problem is the rather strange way you are finding the width of the viewport.

In fact, you aren't.

In this expression:

```
let width  = windowEl.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.body.clientWidth;
```

First windowEl.innerWidth is evaluated. It's not defined - innerWidth doesn't apply here. So the next value is evaluated.

Then I think you have forgotten that browser's add default margins.

At no point do you look at the actual viewport width which can be obtained through `window.innerHTML`